# If I rm -rf a symlink will the data the link points to get erased, too?

Tags: linux, symlink

This is the contents of the `/home3` directory on my system:

```
./   backup/    hearsttr@  lost+found/  randomvi@  sexsmovi@
../  freemark@  investgr@  nudenude@    romanced@  wallpape@
```

I want to clean this up but I am worried because of the symlinks, which point to another drive.

If I say `rm -rf /home3` will it delete the other drive?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`rm -rf /home3` will delete all files and directory within `home3` and `home3` itself, which include symlink files, but will not "follow"(de-reference) those symlink.

Put it in another words, those symlink-files will be deleted. The files they "point"/"link" to will not be touch.

Comment: Note that this is true for `rm -rf /home3`, but not for `rm -rf /home3/`. The latter will remove the target directory and its contents, but will keep the link.

Comment: @FWDekker There is no difference with or without the ending `/`. `home3` is a directory and both its content and itself will be deleted.

Comment: My bad, you're right, I think I misread the question when I commented that. My comment applies to the case where **`/home3` itself is a symlink**: `rm -rf /home3` would only remove the link, but `rm -rf /home3/` would erase all files in the directory that is linked to.

Comment: @FWDekker If `home3` is symlink, then you are right.