# Is it safe to remove a directory that has a mixture of symbolic links and subdirectories?

Tags: symlink, rm

I have a directory, `dir`. Inside `dir`, there are symlinks and regular subdirectories. I want to remove `dir` and create a symlink for `dir` to point to another directory.

If I simply do `rm -rf dir`, I believe this should remove all the subdirectories and symlinks within `dir`, but is this safe to do when there are symlinks within `dir`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I rm -rf a symlink will the data the link points to get erased, too?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62502/if-i-rm-rf-a-symlink-will-the-data-the-link-points-to-get-erased-too)

Comment: @muru I'm not sure because I can't tell if the `/home3` in that question is a symlink? If it isn't, then I think it does

Comment: @muru The title says "if i rm -rf a SYMLINK" which seems to imply /home3 is a symlink

Comment: Is `dir` in your question a symlink?

Comment: @muru No, it's just a regular directory

Comment: The answer there treats `/home3` as a regular directory (see comments) and note that OP's worried about the symlinks within, not about `/homee` itself, so I'm inclined to say it's not a symlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would be safe to remove the directory and its contents using `rm -rf dir`.  That operation would not follow symbolic links and would therefore not remove files or directories that are located outside of `dir`.  [The POSIX specification for `rm`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html) *specifically* mentions this with regard to recursive operation:

> The `rm` utility shall not traverse directories by following symbolic links into other parts of the hierarchy, but shall remove the links themselves.

If `dir` itself is a symbolic link (you say it's a directory, so this may not apply to your situation), then that symbolic link will be removed, but not the thing that it points to.  Note that in this case, `rm -rf dir/` (with the final slash added) would dereference the symbolic link and delete the directory that the link points to, while the symbolic link would remain.

Comment: IIRC whether `rm -rf dir/` where `dir` is a symlink, removes that symlink (and/or the target and its contents) is system / rm implementation dependant.